# when I try to use 'import('./components/Login.vue')' to import a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in TopBar I try to import Login by async way (import()) but there is nothing on screen

```
export default {
  name: "TopBar",
  components:{
    'Login':() => import('./TopBar/Login')  <--here
  },
  setup(){
    const isShow = ref(false)
    return {
      isShow
    }
  }
}
```

In component Login I try to print some information and a problem has arisen.
**[Vue warn]: Invalid VNode type: undefined (undefined)**

Comment: this is vuejs version 3, correct?

Comment: yes,i find i should use defineAsyncComponent /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Comment: was just about to say that :p